# Как в three js сделать конструктор, где каждый параметр зависит от длины, ширины, и высоты?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Необходимо создать дугу квадратной формы, прямо под настилом (коричневенькая штука), есть у кого предложения, как это можно реализовать?

P.S. данная конструкция должна создаваться в конструкторе, где каждый параметр зависит от длины, ширины, и высоты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Blender, 3DMax, SketchUp, Modo - там любые формы делаются.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса ничего не понятно, вы можете конкретизировать что именно вам помочь?

Comment: @Kromster я не просто так указал в условиях three js, здесь необходимо сделать конкретно в оболочке canvas three js, было б всё так просто, я б сделал всё через blender

Comment: @ПростаMiha под настилом есть геометрия изгиба куба, её-то мне и надо построить

Comment: @Kromster потому что это конструктор, каждый параметр напрямую влияет на геометрию, длина, высота, ширина, мне же необходима "дуга", прямо под навесом(коричневенькие штучки), если так понятнее, допустим известен угол, на который эта дуга должна изгибаться, как смастерить эту самую дугу

Comment: @Kromster так что, есть предположения?

Comment: У вас на картинке только навес коричневый ...

Comment: Есть вот такое: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/profiledcontourgeometry/2330, с дальнейшим развитием https://discourse.threejs.org/t/profiledcontourgeometry-multimaterial/5801.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общих чертах, вам скорее всего надо иметь шаблонные части конструкции (стойка, перекладина, секция навеса, итп, сделанные в Blender/3DMax/итп) и собирать из них как из *конструктора* нужную конфигурацию (например 8 стоек, 2 перекладины, 4 секции, как на картинке) в нужных размерах (translate и scale в помощь).

Создавать что-то "из кубов" будет гораздо сложнее и муторнее. Даже если вы сделаете дугу, вы замучаетесь делать для парную нижнюю часть и перемычки.

Comment: то есть вы предлагаете, в blender создать секцию или же варианты секций, и потом их добавлять в canvas на нужные позиции?

Comment: Именно так. Заодно сможете всяких красивостей добавить потом, типа chamfer или UV-текстурирования или головок болтов, если захотите.